# Draw transparent rectangle on YUV-overlay

Tags: python, pygame

Working on a YUV-viewer in python using `pygame`.

The code below displays one frame of YUV 4:2:0

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import pygame

W = 352
H = 288
WH = (W, H)

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(WH)

overlay = pygame.Overlay(pygame.YV12_OVERLAY, WH)

fd = open('foreman.yuv', 'rb')
y = fd.read(W * H)
u = fd.read(W * H / 4)
v = fd.read(W * H / 4)

overlay = pygame.Overlay(pygame.YV12_OVERLAY, WH)

overlay.display((y, u, v))
```

This code displays a 16x16 semi-transparent rectangle in position (0,0)

```
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(WH)

s = pygame.Surface((16,16))
s.set_alpha(128)
s.fill((255,255,255))
screen.blit(s, (0,0))
pygame.display.flip()
```

But, how do I combine them? I.e. how do I display a semi-transparent rectangle in position (0,0) on top of the YUV-data so that the YUV-data can be seen through the rectangle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an OVERLAY.  You can't put other stuff "on top" of it: from the [docs](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/overlay.html):

> The overlay objects are always visible, and always show **above** the
>   regular display contents.

YUV overlays tap into hardware normally used by media players to display video.  The content is typically never written to a "framebuffer" as such (causing endless grief with blank areas for screenshot/screen-capture software etc).

So you'd have to draw what you want to add over it directly "into" the y,u,v data.  (Or convert the y,u,v data to RGB data and display it by more conventional means).

Answer (score 0):

Thought I'd post how i did the conversion from YCbCr a surface in pygame, since I couldn't find any solution using google.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import pygame
import Image
import sys

W = 352
H = 288
WH = (W, H)

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(WH)

fd = open('foreman.yuv', 'rb')
y = fd.read(W * H)
u = fd.read(W * H / 4)
v = fd.read(W * H / 4)
fd.close()

# Use PIL to get a black-n-white version of the YCbCr
# and convert it to RGB
im = Image.fromstring('L', WH, y)
rgb = im.convert('RGB')

s = pygame.image.frombuffer(rgb.tostring(), rgb.size, rgb.mode)

screen.blit(s, (0,0))
pygame.display.flip()
```